# What am I doing wrong and how can I make the gameobject pass on same color and destroy on different?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.cyan, Color.red, Color.yellow, Color.magenta };
private int currentColor, length;
void Start()
{
    currentColor                            = 0; //White
    length                                  = colors.Length;
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[currentColor];
}
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        currentColor                            = (currentColor + 1) % length;
        GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = colors[currentColor];
    }
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.tag != currentColor)
    {
        Destroy(col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

what i want to happen is make the gameobject pass through same color and destroy when it passes through different color

Comment: Please add the solution for your problem as an answer and mark it as the correct answer, so people now your problem is solved and what the solution was thanks in advance.

Comment: i want the ball to get destroyed but the obstcales get destroyed and even if its the same color..it gets destroyed

Comment: ah sry thought you got the answer, will edit mine fast and undelete it.

Comment: If I understood it right each Obstacle is tagged with the number equal to the color in the color array? white obstacle has tag called 0?

Comment: yes they have tags with color name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well simple `tag` is `string`, `currentColor` is integer. You cannot do

```
 col.tag != currentColor
```

What I don't understand is how did you manage to compile it, it shouldn't work at all the way it is written.

Anyway, if you insist to use tags, your code can be rewritten like this:

```
System.Tuple<Color, string>[] colors = new System.Tuple<Color, string>[] {
    new System.Tuple<Color, string> (Color.cyan, "cyan"),
    new System.Tuple<Color, string> (Color.red, "red"),
    new System.Tuple<Color, string> (Color.yellow, "yellow"),
    new System.Tuple<Color, string> (Color.magenta, "magenta")
};
private int currentColor, length;
void Start () {
    currentColor = 0; //White
    length = colors.Length;
    GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = colors[currentColor].Item1;
}
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        currentColor = (currentColor + 1) % length;
        GetComponent<Renderer> ().material.color = colors[currentColor].Item1;
    }
}
void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col) {
    if (col.tag != colors[currentColor].Item2) {
        Destroy (col.gameObject);
    }
}
```

P.S. This will work but if I were you I would not use tags for this case at all.

Comment: thanks it works perfectly but instead of the player the objects gets destroyed

Comment: Well you can just change `Destroy (col.gameObject)` to `Destroy (this.gameObject)` that should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

What if you check the color on Collision `col.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color` and if its not equal to `colors[currentColor]` the player dies.

**Check GameObject with the actual color:**

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) 
{
    // Check if color of the collided GameObject is equal to the current color of the Player
    if(col.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color != colors[currentColor])
    {
        // Destroy Player because he collided with an obstacle
        Destroy(gameObject);
    } 
}
```

**Check GameObject with the tag:**

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col) 
{
    // Check if color of the collided GameObject is equal to the current color of the Player
    // Use CompareTag to get an Error Message when the Tag doesn't exist
    if(!col.CompareTag(currentColor))
    {
        // Destroy Player because he collided with an obstacle
        Destroy(gameObject);
    } 
}
```

Comment: nothing happens on collision and also it gives me error : The local function 'OnTriggerEnter2D' is declared but never used

Comment: Are you sure that the object your script lies upon has IsTrigger Enabled and has Box Collider?

Comment: yup it does have both

Comment: does the object you want to collide with also have a box collider and istrigger disabled?

Comment: yup it is disabled on obstacles

Comment: does your object that the script lies upon have a RigidBody and CollisionDetection to Continous?

Comment: yes it has both..for the tag one i get this error- cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'